# FCM, Not receiving Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I m getting notifications, Title and Body both but not receiving data.

```
{
  "notification":{
    "body":"This is message body",
    "title":"This is Title",
    "click_action":"clickAction",
     "data":{
        "post_id":"post id",
        "update":"no"
        }
    },
 "to":"token"
}
```

this is the json of FCM, everything else is working fine, I m receiving the notification, notification opening a specific page, but I m unable to get the data from the notification.

Here is a function in the `MyFirebaseMessaging.java`

```
  private void showNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, 
  Map<String, String> data) {

    String clickAction = notification.getClickAction();

    Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
    if (data.size() > 0){
        String post_id = data.get("post_id");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("blog_post_id",post_id);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    } else {
        String post_id = "post id";
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("blog_post_id",post_id);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, new Intent[]{intent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

I also tried without bundle but the same result.
In the clickAction activity i m receiving null.
this is the code i used in the ClickAction class to receive the Intent

```
blog_post_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("blog_post_id");
Log.e(TAG,"blog_post_id "+blog_post_id);
```

Edit 1: Problem is solved, for some reason clickAction Activity is receiving getIntent() from other activity and generating null. so I created one more getIntent() and added

```
String id = null;
    try {
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        blog_post_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("blog_post_id");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (id.length() > 0) {
            blog_post_id = id;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: `data` should be _outside_ of `notification`.

Comment: That helped but my problem was different.
The activity was already receiving Intent so I had to make another getIntent() and merge them if anyone of them is null.
I faced this problem 1st time.

Comment: Hi Rahul, do post your solution as an actual answer. [Self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged here in Stack Overflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, for some reason clickAction Activity is receiving `getIntent()` from other activity and generating null. so I created one more `getIntent()` and added.
So i simply merged them and it solved the problem.

The main problem was like -

`Activity1` sending data to `blog_post_id`

`Activity2` also wants to send data to `blog_post_id`,

but because `blog_post_id` need data regularly from `Activity1` it generates `null pointer exception` if it does not received data from `Activity1`,
so i simply take the data of `Activity2` into `String id` and merge both of them.

```
String id = null;
try {
    id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    blog_post_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("blog_post_id");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    if (id.length() > 0) {
        blog_post_id = id;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```